# RSpec. How to check if the object method is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing the spec for controller:

```
it 'should call the method that performs the movies search' do
  movie = Movie.new
  movie.should_receive(:search_similar)
  get :find_similar, {:id => '1'}
end
```

and my controller looks like:

```
def find_similar
 @movies = Movie.find(params[:id]).search_similar
end
```

after running the rspec i get the following:

```
Failures:
1) MoviesController searching by director name should call the method that performs the movies search
 Failure/Error: movie.should_receive(:search_similar)
   (#<Movie:0xaa2a454>).search_similar(any args)
       expected: 1 time
       received: 0 times
 # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

which i seem to understand and accept, because in my controller code i invoke the Class (Movie) method and i don't see any way to connect "find_similar" with object, created in the spec.

So the question is -> what is the way to check if the method is called on the object, created in spec?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
it 'should call the method that performs the movies search' do
  movie = Movie.new
  movie.should_receive(:search_similar)
  Movie.should_receive(:find).and_return(movie)
  get :find_similar, {:id => '1'}
end
```

<sub>For what is worth, I'm totally against these stub-all-things tests, they just make code changes harder and are actually testing nothing but code structure.</sub>

Comment: Agree about over-stubbing, seen too many tests checking that method stubbing works rather than checking that the app works.

Comment: nice one. here's the docs on relish: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-5/docs/message-expectations I needed this bit `obj.should_receive(:message).with('more_than', 'one_argument')`

Comment: interesting use of "<sub></sub>" tags

Answer (score 0):

At first, your movie is not persisted yet.

At second, not fact, that will have id `1`

So try this

```
it 'should call the method that performs the movies search' do
  movie = Movie.create
  movie.should_receive(:search_similar)
  get :find_similar, {:id => movie.id}
end
```

Comment: thanks for "id", you are absolutely right. the main question is however still here, after changing the code the message is the same -> Failure/Error: movie.should_receive(:search_similar)
       (#<Movie:0xae08b48>).search_similar(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times

Comment: It's curiously that in first version of spec `Movie.find(params[:id])` is not raise `RecordNotFound`..